# Get data only one folder not for all folders in treeview - Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

i want to show all folders(images, videos,files) with directories/files, currently only show images folder with files, but other folder are not show. I try to find solution but not found. Here is the code & its screenshot(http://postimg.org/image/wm5ypbk9d/).

**FileManager.java**

```
package com.rim.samples.device.mapactiondemo;

import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.system.KeypadListener;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.TreeField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.TreeFieldCallback;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

public class FilesManager extends MainScreen {

FTPMessages _ftp = null;
String[] fileList;

// ..................
private final Bitmap openIcon = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("open.png");
private final Bitmap closedIcon = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("closed.png");
private final Bitmap movieIcon = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("movie.png");
private final Bitmap songIcon = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("song.png");
private final Bitmap playIcon = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("play.png");
private final Bitmap imgIcon = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("images.png");
String nodeTen;
int node10;
TreeField myTree;
String[] nodeData;

// ListField to be displayed - null - no Field displayed
// List of entries to be displayed - null or length = 0 means no entries
// protected so that another Thread can update this list....
protected ListDirectory[] _resultsList = null; // entries available for
// display

private ListDirectory _selectedEntry = null;

public FilesManager(FTPMessages ftp) {
    super();
    _ftp = ftp;
    // Setting starting directory
    try {
        /*
         * fileList = _ftp.list(); for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++)
         * { _ftp.cwd(fileList[i]); }
         */
        _ftp.cwd("images");
        _ftp.cwd("files");
        _ftp.cwd("videos");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    this.setTitle("Server File List");

    TreeCallback myCallback = new TreeCallback();
    myTree = new TreeField(myCallback, Field.FOCUSABLE) {
        protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
            // We'll only override unvarnished navigation click behavior
            if ((status & KeypadListener.STATUS_ALT) == 0
                    && (status & KeypadListener.STATUS_SHIFT) == 0) {
                final int node = getCurrentNode();
                if (getFirstChild(node) == -1) {
                    // Click is on a leaf node. Do some default action or
                    // else fall through.

                    // Note: this will also detect empty folders, which
                    // might or
                    // might not be something your app has to handle
                    Dialog.alert("clicked " + getCookie(node));
                    // TODO: open player screen, etc.
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return super.navigationClick(status, time);
        }
    };

    myTree.setDefaultExpanded(false);
    myTree.setRowHeight(openIcon.getHeight());

    try {
        node10 = myTree.addChildNode(0, _ftp.pwd());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    this.add(myTree);

    refreshList();
}

private void refreshList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    _resultsList = null;
    String[] directory = null;
    try {
        directory = _ftp.list();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    if (directory != null && directory.length > 0) {
        _resultsList = new ListDirectory[directory.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < directory.length; i++) {
            _resultsList[i] = new ListDirectory(directory[i],
                    ListDirectory.UNIX_SERVER);
        }
    }

    if (_resultsList != null && _resultsList.length > 0) {
        // we have some results
        for (int i = 0; i < _resultsList.length; i++) {
            String bb = directory[i];
            String nodeFive = new String(bb);
            this.myTree.addChildNode(node10, nodeFive);
        }

    } else {

    }
}

private class TreeCallback implements TreeFieldCallback {
    public void drawTreeItem(TreeField _tree, Graphics g, int node, int y,
            int width, int indent) {
        final int PAD = 8;
        String text = (String) _tree.getCookie(node);
        Bitmap icon = closedIcon;
        if (text.endsWith(".mp3")) {
            icon = songIcon;
        } else if (text.endsWith(".avi")) {
            icon = movieIcon;
        } else if (text.endsWith(".png") || text.endsWith(".jpg")) {
            icon = imgIcon;
        } else if (_tree.getExpanded(node)) {
            icon = openIcon;
        }
        g.drawBitmap(indent, y, icon.getWidth(), icon.getHeight(), icon, 0,
                0);
        // This assumes filenames all contain '.' character!
        if (text.indexOf(".") > 0) {
            // Leaf node, so this is a playable item (movie or song)
            g.drawBitmap(_tree.getWidth() - playIcon.getWidth() - PAD, y
                    + PAD, playIcon.getWidth(), playIcon.getHeight(),
                    playIcon, 0, 0);
        }
        int fontHeight = getFont().getHeight();
        g.drawText(text, indent + icon.getWidth() + PAD,
                y + (_tree.getRowHeight() - fontHeight) / 2);
    }
}

}
```

The other classes that used with this code, download from that link(complete project classes)
http://remote.offroadstudios.com/files/filemanager.zip

you can also check files on server, ip:64.207.150.31:21, username:remote, password:123456789

Comment: **What is your question**?  We are not here to write your app for you.  You need to break your app into many, **small** problems.  Ask about **one problem at a time**.  Until you do that, people are going to keep closing your questions.  This one is not much better than your first one.  Please spend a few minutes looking around Stack Overflow, and reading some of the other questions here.  Look at which *kinds* of questions are asked.  Do not keep asking us to write a large application for you, in one big question.

Comment: @Nate, I update the question, please can see where i mistake or any help??

Comment: I am still not clear on where your problem is, and there seems to be load of extraneous information supplied.  I think you need to work through the code and supply just the code that demonstrates the problem, nothing more.  But I wonder if you have a design flaw.  Summarising the code, it seems you do this - _ftp.cwd(<directory>) - and then need to do this - _ftp.list() - to get the contents,  But you only seem to do one list() method call.  So perhaps you are not getting the other file names because you never actually ask for them?

Comment: @PeterStrange - Exactly i want this. i only seem one list() of images, but i want to show all list like videos & files. how can i get all the list ??